# Error with firebase deploy only functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have issue with firebase i try to deploy a new functions but i got this error:

> Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logsFunctions deploy had errors with the following functions:api

my index.js in the functions folder is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")("--TOKEN_HERE--");

// API

// - App config
const app = express();

// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  console.log("Payment Request Recieved BOOM!!! for this amount >>> ", total);

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total, // subunits of the currency
    currency: "usd",
  });

  // OK - Created
  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific error that identifies what's wrong with this code.

Comment: I was able to deploy your function successfully. The error you are facing may be due to environment setup.
Could you share the logs mentioned in the error message and share the error that you see?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: could be your version of Nodejs, hard to say without more info--I had this problem deploying using v15 and remarkably fixed using v14 instead